# Full calendar, un boton para actualizar eventos

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

Estoy intentando hacer que `full calendar` refresque los datos mediante un botón, los registros los introduzco en un formulario aparte, pero cuando entro en el calendario tengo que pulsar <kbd>F5</kbd> en el navegador para que muestre los últimos eventos introducidos, lo he intentado con este código `javascript` pero no funciona:

```
 $('#refresh_cal').puibutton();
        $("#zdk_cal_act .bt-refresh_cal").click(function () {

             $("#calendar").fullCalendar("refetchEvents");
        });
```

¿Alguna sugerencia? Los eventos los introduzco por `json`.

El código lo tengo tal como muestro a continuación:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

            header: {

                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,listMonth'
            },

            defaultDate: '<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>',
            defaultView:'listMonth',
            editable: false,
            navLinks: true,
            timeFormat: 'H(:mm)', // uppercase H for 24-hour clock
            weekNumbers: true,
            weekNumbersWithinDays: true,
            weekNumberCalculation: 'ISO',
            businessHours: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            events: <?php echo json_encode($thejson); ?>

        });

    });

</script>

<script>
    $('#refresh_cal').puibutton();
    $("#zdk_cal_act .bt-refresh_cal").click(function () {
        $("#calendar").fullCalendar("refetchEvents");

    });
</script>
<div class="card-content table-responsive" id="zdk_cal_act" >
    <button class="bt-refresh_cal" id="refresh_cal">Actualizar</button>
    <div id="calendar"></div>
</div>
```

Saludos

Comment: ¿Donde tienes colocado ese código del `jQuery`? En qué zona del código

Comment: user3075969, bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour), 
puede tratar de mejorar su pregunta mirando este [enlace](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
es posible que su pregunta sea cerrada o puesta en espera no se lo tome a mal, 
para mas información consulte el siguiente [enlace](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). 
Saludos